# Django upload file using get method

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I would like to upload a single file or files at a time using get method.

I have already done with the post method and working fine. But for some reason i would like to do the file upload using get method using command line.

The below code is which i have already tried to get the string from get method and i can able to get the varValue as string. But i would like to get the file using get method.

```py
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        varValue = request.GET.get('myfile', '')
        print(varValue)`
```

HTML code:

```html
<form method="GET"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input  type="file" name="myfile" accept="image/*" multiple>
<button type="submit">Upload files</button>
```

Comment: you can check the django documentation about upload files https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/file-uploads/

Comment: Hi @DimitrisKougioumtzis i have checked the documentation already and i'm not able to find the get method file upload. All the things are using post method with csrf_token.

Comment: Why do you want to use GET method instead of POST?

Comment: request.FILES exists if file exists in form , so you can use it with get or post method

Comment: @JPG for uploading the file using requests module using python file in command line for automation. So i have tried post method by skipping the csrf_token verification. But i cant able to upload from python script using requests module. That's why i'm like to upload via get method.

Comment: You can remove csrf validation from the view. I don't think you could upload a file using GET method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution using the post method itself. By skipping the csrf token we can do the command line script execution method.

Python views.py code below

```
 from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
@csrf_exempt
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['myfile']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        name = fs.save(uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file)
        print(name)
    return render(request, "home.html")
```

HTML code:

```
<body>
        <form method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input  type="file" name="myfile" accept="image/*" multiple>
            <button type="submit">Upload files</button>
</body>
```

python code for file upload using post method:

```
import requests
files = {'myfile': open('d:\\20190819-140341-627485.png','rb')}
y = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000",files=files)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Method

```
for filename, file in request.FILES.iteritems():
name = request.FILES[filename].name
```

A dictionary-like object containing all uploaded files. Each key in FILES is the name from the . Each value in FILES is an UploadedFile.

```
 <form method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <input type="file" name="myfile">
  <button type="submit">Upload File</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: if we are using csrf_token we will only get the token as parameter. How can i get that file using request.FILES in get method ?

Comment: Use Post Method

Comment: csrf token  is used in post method only

Comment: i already have post method working perfectly. As i have already mentioned that i would like to use the only way of get method. Thanks